# Unrecognized locale cb_IQ. WARNING ITMS-90176

Tags: ios

When I'm trying to upload my app to app store I get this warning:

WARNING ITMS-90176: "Unrecognized Locale - The directories located at ( "Payload/SaveMe.app/AccountKitStrings.bundle/Resources/cb_IQ.lproj" ) have an unrecognized locale name. Refer to the Language and Locale Designations guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html for more information on naming your language-specific directories."

I didn't find any solution how to fix it. Anybody knows?

Comment: Your link is dead, but according to [this information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/languages) Kurdish (cb_IQ) is not available under iOS.

Comment: So, what i supose to do? Just delete cb_IQ.lproj from AccountKit.bundle?

Answer (score 1):

just remove cb_IQ.lproj, because its format is incompatible with xcode 9. Review the impact of removing that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by deleting the offending resources in your `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
    system("/bin/rm -rf Pods/AccountKit/AccountKitStrings.bundle/Resources/cb_IQ.lproj")
    system("/bin/rm -rf Pods/AccountKit/AccountKit.framework/AccountKitStrings.bundle/Resources/cb_IQ.lproj")
end
```